# How to get Response Headers upon HTTP Request?

Tags: http, http-headers, jwt, elm

I have the following code where I make a post request and I have set Authorization header with JWToken in my server. I wish to extract the JWToken from the response header and save it in local storage using port. 
How to get hold of the Response? I see Metadata which has Headers in the Response type. ref - https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/latest/Http#Response

```
type Msg
  = EnteredEmail String
  | EnteredPassword String
  | SubmittedForm
  | RegistrationSuccess (Result Http.Error ())


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
  case msg of

    EnteredEmail email ->
      updateForm (\form -> { form | email = email }) model

    EnteredPassword password ->
      updateForm (\form -> { form | password = password }) model

    RegistrationSuccess _->
      -- TODO save JWT in local storage on successful registration
      (model, Cmd.none)

    SubmittedForm ->
      -- TODO validate the form
      (model, postCall model)


postCall : Model -> Cmd Msg
postCall model = Http.post {
          url = "http://localhost:9000/register",
          body = Http.jsonBody (
            Json.Encode.object[
              ("age", Json.Encode.int 30),
              ("email", Json.Encode.string model.form.email),
              ("password", Json.Encode.string model.form.password)
            ]
          ),
          expect = Http.expectWhatever RegistrationSuccess
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get to the `Response` and headers by using [`Http.expectStringResponse`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/latest/Http#expectStringResponse) or [`Http.expectBytesResponse`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/latest/Http#expectBytesResponse) instead of `Http.expectWhatever`.

Here's an example that defines a convenience function `expectJWT` which will retrieve and return the `Authorization` header, or if it does not exist returns `BadStatus 403`. In `postCall` all that's changed is that `Http.expectWhatever` has been replaced with `expectJWT`:

```
expectJWT : (Result Http.Error String -> msg) -> Http.Expect msg
expectJWT toMsg =
    Http.expectStringResponse toMsg <|
        \response ->
            case response of
                Http.BadUrl_ url ->
                    Err (Http.BadUrl url)

                Http.Timeout_ ->
                    Err Http.Timeout

                Http.NetworkError_ ->
                    Err Http.NetworkError

                Http.BadStatus_ metadata body ->
                    Err (Http.BadStatus metadata.statusCode)

                Http.GoodStatus_ metadata body ->
                    metadata.headers
                        |> Dict.get "Authorization"
                        |> Result.fromMaybe (Http.BadStatus 403)

postCall : Model -> Cmd Msg
postCall model = Http.post {
          url = "http://localhost:9000/register",
          body = Http.jsonBody (
            Json.Encode.object[
              ("age", Json.Encode.int 30),
              ("email", Json.Encode.string model.form.email),
              ("password", Json.Encode.string model.form.password)
            ]
          ),
          expect =  expectJWT RegistrationSuccess
        }
```